# how to send an emails to a list while updating MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, email

i have wrote a php script to send an emails.In this script it checks whether current date is equal with the emailfly_date and email is = o.if that satisfies email will sent to the user.this script is working for one user at a one time.that if database has five records that that matches current criteria it sends the email only to the last id.what is the reason for this?

id

250
251
252
253

it will send the email only to the ID 253.but not to the others.

Here is mycode

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';



    $query = "SELECT ID,email, emailfly_date, CURRENT_DATE AS nowtime FROM xxx WHERE reqnum = '' AND email_sent = '0'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $regid = $row['ID'];
        $activemail= $row['nowtime'];
        /*echo $regid . '<br />';
        echo $activemail. '<br />';*/
    }


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, email, reqnum, emailfly_date, email_sent FROM xxx WHERE ID = '$regid' AND emailfly_date = '$activemail'");

    $rowdata = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        $ID = $rowdata['ID'];
        $email = $rowdata['email'];
        $reqnum = $rowdata['reqnum'];
        $emailfly_date = $rowdata['emailfly_date'];
        $email_sent = $rowdata['email_sent'];


        if ($reqnum != '') {
           /* echo "not sucess";*/

        } elseif ($email_sent == '1') {
           /* echo "email already sent";*/

        } elseif ($email_sent == '1' && $reqnum != '') {
           /* echo "no way to send";*/
        }
        elseif($email_sent == '0' && $reqnum == '' ){


            $ulink = "http://xxx.eewfewt.net/tttt/yyyy.php?ID=$regid";

            $to = $email;

            $subject = 'hoo'; // Give the email a subject
            $message = '

            Thanks for Using  Trial Version!
            If You Wish to Continue  with the Monthly Paid Package.

            ------------------------
            Click Below 

            Site Renewal link: ' . $ulink . '
            '.$emailfly_date.'
            ------------------------ ';


            $headers .= 'From:werwerwer.aaa.net' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Bcc:ewrwerer.aaa.net' . "\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            $upadtequery = mysql_query("UPDATE xxx SET email_sent ='1' WHERE ID = '$regid'");


            echo "sucess";

        }
else{
   echo "bye";

}




?>
```

Comment: below the first query execution you are saving the multiple values in same variable.. $regid = $row['ID'];  it overrides the existing data and saves the new data.. so it only executes the last value.

Comment: you should use your email code within while loop.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: I think just one error there, please print the $rowdata and check how you get the data.

Answer (score 0):

From    `$query = mysql_query(.....bla...bla...` to last `else{
            echo "bye";
        }` Put all this inside your `while` loop. 
Also if you fetch data from same table try to use single query.
mysql_*() is depreciated now. So try to use mysqli_*()

Answer (score 0):

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

```
$query = "SELECT ID,email, emailfly_date, CURRENT_DATE AS nowtime FROM xxx WHERE id in ('250','251','252','253') AND email_sent = '0'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($rowdata = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ID = $rowdata['ID'];
    $email = $rowdata['email'];
    $reqnum = $rowdata['reqnum'];
    $emailfly_date = $rowdata['emailfly_date'];
    $email_sent = $rowdata['email_sent'];
    $ulink = "http://xxx.eewfewt.net/tttt/yyyy.php?ID=$regid";
    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'hoo'; // Give the email a subject
    $message = '

    Thanks for Using  Trial Version!
    If You Wish to Continue  with the Monthly Paid Package.

    ------------------------
    Click Below 

    Site Renewal link: ' . $ulink . '
    '.$emailfly_date.'
    ------------------------ ';
    $headers .= 'From:werwerwer.aaa.net' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc:ewrwerer.aaa.net' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $upadtequery = mysql_query("UPDATE xxx SET email_sent ='1' WHERE ID = '$ID'");
    echo "sucess";

}
```